# Remove all duplicated entries but not the first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+ id + lastSeen   + lastSeenMS + value +
| 1  | 1509272314 |     123    |   12  |
| 2  | 1509272314 |     123    |   19  |
| 3  | 1509272314 |     123    |   17  |
| 4  | 1509272532 |     453    |   25  |
```

Now I need to delete all but the first entry which have the same `lastSeen` and `lastSeenMS` value.

I thought about using `GROUP BY lastSeen, lastSeenMS` but I am not sure how to only delete the last entries and not the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID)
                 FROM table_name
                 GROUP BY lastSeen, lastSeenMS);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ZERMIF96454)**

The record with lowest ID per group will stay in table.
Warning! Use this method only when `ID` is `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`.

---

**EDIT:**

Same logic as above, but applied to MySQL dialect:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tab t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID
           FROM tab
           GROUP BY lastSeen, lastSeenMS) t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/TXL91858)**

Comment: Is there a way around this: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'record' for update in FROM clause`
I guess its because it is the same database where I run a select and a delete